# Formatting Cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format cells in a google sheet based on columns before it in the row.  For example, I have check boxes in B1 and C1, if both of them are unchecked (false) I would like D1 to turn red; but only if 2 in a row are unchecked. So if B1 & C1 are unchecked, then D1 is red; but if B1 is checked and C1 is unchecked, I want D1 to still be white.  Is there a formula for this?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Applied to range D1 (or D1:D if you want the following custom CF formula to apply to the entire Column D):

```
=B1+C1=0
```

Format as desired (i.e., red fill).

Comment: This worked - so simple...  Thank you!!  I was making it harder than it was.

Comment: Glad to help simplify, Danielle. Would you take a moment now to mark my post as "Best Answer"? It doesn't earn me any free donuts. But it does alert the community at large that the issue has been resolved; and it helps future users more easily arrive at answers to their similar questions.